# AWS CloudFormation error: Could not create Change Set "change-set-name" due to: Parameters: "[ssm:param-name:167:167710252826] cannot be found

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a CF template (serverless Typescript file to be precise) which creates a container definition in the following way.

```
Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
Properties: {
  Family: "client", 
  RequiresCompatibilities: ["FARGATE"],
  NetworkMode: "awsvpc",
  Memory: 1024,
  CPU: 512,
  TaskRoleArn: { Ref: ECS_TASK_ROLE },
  ExecutionRoleArn: { Ref: ECS_TASK_ROLE },
  ContainerDefinitions: [
    {
      Name: application,
      Essential: true,
      Image: `${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository:client-{{resolve:ssm:param-name}}`,
      .
      .
      .
    },
  ],
}
```

Please note the usage of AWS SSM Dynamic Reference.
When I deploy it I get the following error

```
Could not create Change Set "change-set-name" due to: Parameters: "[ssm:param-name:167:167710252826] cannot be found.
```

It used to work fine and all of a sudden started breaking. Same code still works in a different env/AWS account.

Seems like it can't find a specific version of param-name for some reason. The latest param-name verion is 400. AWS SSM only keeps last 100 params. This parameter is updated quite often and it's been a long time since I deployed CF template. From the error message it seems like it is looking for version 167 (I could be wrong because I am not sure what is the number trailing 167 i.e. `167:167710252826`)

### What I tried:

I hardcoded the version number I pass as below and removed all the references to `resolve:ssm:param-name`.

```
Image: `${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository:client-1.6.3`,
```

It still throws the same error. Which hints that the problem is not related to code. CF is trying to run an old change set from history to create a diff and can't find an old version of the same param.

What could be the solution to this?

I can't delete the old change set. It throws an error on deleting.
I can't go back and create a parameter in SSM with version 167 if it's a version issue.

Comment: I agree the problem appears to be a stale change-set you are stuck with.  Just FYI, [here is how the parameter version should work in the CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html):  [version
An integer that specifies the version of the parameter to use. If you don't specify the exact version, CloudFormation uses the latest version of the parameter whenever you create or update the stack. For more information, see Working with parameter versions in the AWS Systems Manager User Guide

Optional.]